# A solution of a linear system in some extension field implies a solution in the subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, extension-field

> Fix a field extension $k\subseteq K$ and consider a  linear system $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a matrix (not necessarily square) with coefficients in $k$. I don't understand why if the above linear system has a solution in $K$, then there exists also a solution in $k$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For square matrices this is a consequence of Cramer's rule. Maybe you can generalize this to your problem.

Comment: In my case, the matrix is not square. This is the point.

Comment: The algorithm for finding the set of solutions to a linear system is immune to the existence of an extension field of $k$. For example the reduced row echelon form of $A$ remains the same. As does that of $(A|b)$. The claim follows from this.

Comment: The proposed duplicate focuses on how the real numbers extend the rationals, but Jyrki has identified the crux of the argument that applies in all field extension settings.  Row reduction is our friend.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a $k$-linear projection $\pi:K\to k$.  Applying $(\pi,\ldots,\pi)$ to both sides of $Ax=b$, we see that if $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a solution, so is $(\pi(x_1),\ldots,\pi(x_n))$.

Comment: This may lead to a trivial solution in $k,$ isn't it?

Comment: If $b=0$, then yes, it's possible.

Comment: So arbitrary projections cannot guarantee a solution in $k.$

Comment: Why not?  The trivial solution is still a solution.

Comment: If you have $b=0$ and you're trying to avoid the trivial solution, then if $x_jneq 0$ (for some $j$), you can choose a projection with $\pi(x_j) \neq 0$. (if $x_j\notin k$, pick a basis of $K/k$ that includes $1$ and $x_j - 1$)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I meant the statement, exactly, should be that the existences of non-trivial solutions in field extensions are equivalent, and arbitrary projection cannot serve the work. Of course the way how you picked a particular projection in the last comment is undoubytly correct!

Comment: @Slade how do know a projection $\pi$ exists?

Comment: @Math_Day This is a general fact about vector spaces: there exists a projection onto any subspace.  If you choose a $k$-basis for $K$, any nonzero function on the basis extends to such a projection.